# Optimizing task allocation in a calendar by duration limit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

About project - It is a calendar application where each day will have some task accourding to time limit user want to select. Time limit can be selected from dropdown which has options of 2hrs, 4hrs and 6hrs.

I have an array of task objects, each with a duration property specified in minutes. I want to display as many tasks as possible in each day of the calendar starting from current date such that the total duration of the tasks on any given day does not exceed the selected "hours" value.

For example, if the durations of the tasks are 50, 40, 20, 60, 50, 20, 30, 45, 45 and the hour value is 2, then the first three tasks should go to the current date because their combined duration (50 + 40 + 20) is lesser than 2*60 = 120 minutes, which is the maximum duration limit for that day. The remaining tasks should be allocated to the next available dates.
current date - 50, 40, 20
next date - 60, 50
next date - 20, 30, 45
next date - 45

```
const courses = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "React Query",
      description: "Learn how to use React Query",
      type: "video",
      duration: 40
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "MCQ Challenge for React Query",
      description: "See if you understood the concepts with this MCQ.",
      type: "coursemcq",
      duration: 50
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Coding Challenge with React Query",
      description: "Apply the React Query Concept here",
      type: "codingchallenge",
      duration: 20
    },
    ]
```

this is my code -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Calendar.css";
import { courses } from "./course";

const Calendar = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [hours, setHours] = useState("2");

  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    const newDate = new Date(startDate);
    newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + page);
    setStartDate(newDate);
  };

  const getDaysInMonth = (date) => {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  };

  const getMonthDates = (startDate) => {
    const daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(startDate);
    const monthDates = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
      const date = new Date(startDate);
      date.setDate(i);
      monthDates.push(date);
    }

    return monthDates;
  };

  const monthDates = getMonthDates(startDate);

  const daysOfWeek = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];

  const monthYear = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
  }).format(startDate);

  const [startIndx, setStartIndx] = useState(0);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const getTasks = () => {
    let totalDuration = 0;
    setTasks([]);
    for (let i = startIndx; i < courses.length; i++) {
      totalDuration = totalDuration + courses[i].duration;
      if (totalDuration <= hours * 60) {
        console.log(courses[i]);
        setTasks([...tasks, courses[i]]);
      } else {
        console.log("false");
        setStartIndx(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="hours">Hours:</label>
        <select
          id="hours"
          value={hours}
          onChange={(e) => setHours(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
          <option value="4">4 Hours</option>
          <option value="6">6 Hours</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handlePageChange(-1)}>Previous</button>
        <button onClick={() => handlePageChange(1)}>Next</button>
      </div>
      <h2>{monthYear}</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {daysOfWeek.map((day) => (
              <th key={day}>{day}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {monthDates.map((date, index) => {
            if (index % 7 === 0) {
              const weekStartDate = new Date(date);
              weekStartDate.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);

              return (
                <tr key={weekStartDate}>
                  {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((day) => {
                    const cellDate = new Date(weekStartDate);
                    cellDate.setDate(weekStartDate.getDate() + day);

                    // I think i am calling this getTasks in wrong positon
                    // getTasks();

                    return (
                      <td key={cellDate}>
                        {cellDate.getMonth() === startDate.getMonth() && (
                          <span>
                            Date: {cellDate.getDate()}
                            {/* showing all task here */}
                            {tasks.map((el) => (
                              <span>{el.title}</span>
                            ))}
                          </span>
                        )}
                      </td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

I call this function, then it will go infinite loop

```
// I think i am calling this getTasks in wrong positon
getTasks();
```

I am not getting why this function call is creating infinite loop, i think my logic in getTasks of dividing tasks is right.

I want to optimize the allocation of tasks to days such that each day has the maximum number of tasks possible within the specified duration limit. How can I achieve this in my calendar application?

you can check this code in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-framework-h4grxi?file=/src/Calendar.jsx) in codesandbox.

Comment: Your logic of getting Tasks seems to be right. But you cannot call function in the render. Because you are changing the state in that function and whenever state changes your component is re-rendered.

Comment: What you can do probably is, create an array with key, value pair something like [currentDate -> Tasks, nextDate -> Tasks]. And use this array do display courses on calendar. you don't need to store them in state.